# Is it possible to plot a 3-variable function, two variables normally, and the third one to change with color?

Tags: plotting, color, variable, plot-themes

I have a function like
$$f(x,y,z)=4 \sinh (2 y) \cosh (z-x)+5 \sin (2 x-y)-6 x+y+3 \cosh (2 z)$$
where
$$0<x<4\;,\qquad-3<y<0\;,\qquad0<z<2$$

I would like to have a plot of this function for the **two variables $x,y$ as a 2D plot**, and the third **variable $z$ changes with color** ( `ColorFunction` for example from Blue to Red) **with the step $0.01$**, something like this

[image]

> **Is it possible to do this?**

The function

```
f[x_, y_, z_] :=  5 Sin[2 x - y] + 3 Cosh[2 z] - 6 x + 4 Sinh[2 y] Cosh[z - x] + y
```

Comment: For every point `{x,y}` you intend to plot the two quantities   `z`  and(!)   `f[x,y,z]`? How should that work?

Comment: I think we need more information about how you expect x, y, z, and f to be represented in the plot.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You are right, my question is wrong.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I meant instead of a function, an equation; I have asked a new question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246656/how-to-plot-solutions-of-a-3-variable-equation-two-variables-normally-and-the)

Comment: @BrettChampion I meant instead of a function, an equation; I have asked a new question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246656/how-to-plot-solutions-of-a-3-variable-equation-two-variables-normally-and-the)

Answer (score 2):

You have four dimensions `{x, y, z, f}`

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_, z_] := 
 5 Sin[2 x - y] + 3 Cosh[2 z] - 6 x + 4 Sinh[2 y] Cosh[z - x] + y

ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z],
 {x, 0, 4}, {y, -3, 0}, {z, 0, 2},
 Contours -> {50, 0, -50, -150, -400},
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic,
   LegendLabel -> Style[f, 14, Bold]],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z})]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@
  Table[f[x, y, z], {z, 0, 2, 0.5}],
 {x, 0, 4}, {y, -3, 0},
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Range[0, 2, 0.5],
   LegendLabel -> Style[z, 14, Bold]],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, f}),
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[f[x, y, z], {x, 0, 4}, {y, -3, 0},
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
    LegendLabel -> Style[f, 14, Bold]],
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y})],
 {{z, 1, Style["z", 14, Bold]}, 0, 2, 0.1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, even though now I know that my question was wrong.