# How to plot solutions of a 3-variable equation, two variables normally, and the third one to change with colors?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, color, plot-themes

I have this three variable equation
$$4 \sinh (2 y) \cosh (z-x)+5 \sin (2 x-y)-6 x+y+3 \cosh (2 z)=0$$
where
$$0<x<4\;,\qquad-3<y<0\;,\qquad0<z<2$$

I want to have a continuous plot (by joining the adjacent points) of the solutions of the equation for the **two variables $x,y$ in 2D**, and the third **variable $z$ changes with color** ( `ColorFunction` for example from Blue to Red) **with the step $0.01$**, something like this

[image]

> **Is it possible to do this?**

The equation

```
 5 Sin[2 x - y] + 3 Cosh[2 z] - 6 x + 4 Sinh[2 y] Cosh[z - x] + y==0
```

[image]

Comment: I think you might have some problems with this strategy: for each `x`, `y` there are multiple `z` that solve the equation (even when restricting to the reals), so the question of what color the point at `x`, `y` should be arises. To see this consider `N@Solve[5 Sin[2 x - y] + 3 Cosh[2 z] - 6 x + 4 Sinh[2 y] Cosh[z - x] + y == 0, z] /. {x -> 2, y -> -2}`. However, if you have a way of picking just one `z` at each point that you want to show, it should be possible (but that method would be noncanonical, and up to you)

Comment: @thorimur Thanks. I thought we can calculate the points $(x,y,z)$ which solves this equation, then, ask Mathematica to join the adjacent points and give a continuous line.

Comment: ah, somehow i totally missed the restrictions on $z$! I was wrong that this is an issue; those restrictions turn out to be enough to make your idea work and to make the $z$-value at a given $x,y$ unique. cvgmt's solution works. :)

Comment: You can edit you original question to clarify your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `ContourPlot3D` and `ColorFunction` for `z`.

```
ContourPlot3D[
 5 Sin[2 x - y] + 3 Cosh[2 z] - 6 x + 4 Sinh[2 y] Cosh[z - x] + y == 
  0, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -3, 0}, {z, 0, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]], 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> Top, 
 Axes -> {True, True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I meant to see the change of $z$ (with step $0.01$) in your black curves with different colors., something like manipulating the variable $z$ but with colors. Is it possible?

Comment: @MsMath `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, Red}, {1, Blue}}, #3] &)` ?

Comment: No, something like the second picture I have added to the text. Is it possible to show the change of $z$ like that?

Comment: I mean using `ContourPlot3D` for the three variables $x,y,z$ where the behaviour of $z$ is shown by changing its colour.